# Editing .bin (binary) (hex) file in Powerbuilder 12

Tags: hex, powerbuilder

I have an app where I allow the user to enter data and then I'd like to open a .bin file, search for a particular position and then paste the data the user entered into the file.

Not sure how to go about doing this, looked over all of the FileOpen, FileRead, FileWriteEx but can't come up with a solution.  What I'm doing now is opening up the file in a Hex Editor, searching for a particular string and then pasting the text.  Doing this all manually, would like to figure out a way to do it automatically.

Is this possible in PB?  What I'm pasting into the .bin file is actual text.
Below is an example....opening up in Hex editor and searching for 'Test...', once I find it then I skip 3 positions and paste my text.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsVxS.png

[Result after PB pastes text into .bin file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymig1.png)

Comment: So all you want the user to do is to enter the string?  The application would do the search and then paste automatically? (no verification by the user of the position in the file)

Comment: Correct, no verification by the user.  There would be 32 different positions on where the text would be pasted but I would know which position it is, user wouldn't have to verify.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a dll in .Net which communicates with PB via COM.  The dll would handle the Hex editing of the file after the PB application sends it the string entered by the user.

Comment: I was able to figure out the spot in the .bin file to paste my text using FileSeek but as soon as I use FileWrite to paste, I get the below result.  So it's pasting the text correctly but I want the data on the LEFT side to reflect what I pasted.  Any way I can achieve this?

Comment: I added an additional link in my original question to show what happens after PB uses FileWrite to paste the text in the .bin file.  Trying to display the '054879B3.....' in the left side of the HEX editor......is this possible?

Comment: I am able to do this in Python, when writing to a file and you send it in this format ('\x07\x59\xED\x1F') Python will write it to the file as a hex value, NOT a string value.  Looking to do this exact same thing in PB but so far I'm unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the hex codes the user inputs to integers, then use the `char` function to convert them to characters. It's those characters you need to write to the file.

Comment: I have a string the user enters, say it's '14'.  How do I convert this to an int, obviously Int('14') will return me 14 (when I'm looking for the integer value of 20).

Comment: I know I can use ls_string = '~h14' to get the character I need to write to my file but PB will not let me store a string variable '~h' where I can concatenate this with my user entered string of '14'.  I saw a workaround in here to set a variable to '~~h' and this seemed to work as I have '~h14' but PB won't recognize this as a hex value.

Comment: I HAVE to explicitly say String ls_test = '~h14' for me to get the correct character value back once I convert it to a blob and write it to my file.  But as I mentioned before, '14' is user input so I would need a way to concatenate it with '~h'.

Comment: Essentialy what I need to create is the following string: "~h14~h59~hBC~hD7" (the user entered 14,59,BC,D7).  As I said before, i would need to store '~h' in a string variable but can't find a workaround.  Any further help would be greatly appreciated...thank you.

Comment: You have to parse the value the user entered and convert it yourself. So for 2 char codes take the first, convert to int, multiply by 16. Then take the second char, convert to int, and add to the first value.